# Angular passes undefined when a field is blank

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form with mandatory and non mandatory fields. If I do not enter any data into the non mandatory fields, undefined is passed by default instead of a null string/ empty object/ empty Array. As a result, this variable is not stored in the DB at all

Is there any Generic way to pass an empty string/object/array instead of undefined when the field is left blank?

Comment: Could you post what you have done so far? See [/help/mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

You can initialize the model with a space using [**ngInit**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) directive. Like

```
<input type="text" ng-model="testModel" ng-init="testModel=' '" />
```

This way the model is always initialized to space character and will be sent in the query parameter therefore it will stored in the database. If the user types any text the value will be updated in model.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In my app, I'm not refreshing the page once the form is submitted. So this works only when I'm adding the form for the first time. If I try to add again without refreshing the page, undefined gets stored.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution would be to initialize all the model values to empty string/array or whatever you want in the controller.

So in your controller, you can initialize all the fields to empty values like

```
$scope.textFieldModel = " ";
$scope.testArray = [];
...
```

Another alternative would be to check for `undefined` values in the service and initialize them to empty if found `undefined`.

```
.service('testService', ['$http' function($http) {
          this.getAll = function(textFieldModel, testArray) {
            return $http({
                          method : 'GET',
                          url : "xyz",
                          params : {
                                    textFieldModel : textFieldModel || " ",
                                    testArray : testArray || []
                                   }
                          })
           }
}])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm looking at making this generic. Initializing all the fields is not the best solution IMO.